# What is significance of MIC-R2 in mine function in Minerva Package R

Tags: r, statistics

The `minerva` package in R provides the value of Maximal Information Coefficient(MIC) of two vectors ,two matrices. The `mine()` function which returns the MIC value ,also returns some other parameters value. One of them is MIC-R2. from the help option I came to know MIC-R2 means the difference between MIC and Pearson's coefficient.

In minerva package,

```
  [MIC,MEV, MCN,MIC-R2]=mine(X,Y,..)
```

What is the statistical significance of MIC-R2 rather than MIC for detecting correlations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MIC and R^2 are both methods for detecting correlations. MIC-R^2 is not for detecting a correlation, it is a measure of the non-linearity of the relationship in question. The higher it is, the more non-linear the relationship is.

The Pearson Correlation Coefficient, let's call it R, can be thought of as a measure of how well the data fits a linear regression line (best-fit line). However, R can be negative, so people like to use R^2 instead because it basically does the same thing and it is between 0 and 1.

MIC is also between 0 and 1, but unlike R^2, it gives high values to non-linear relationships. Therefore, these two will be very similar (MIC-R^2 close to 0) when there is a linear relationship and very different (MIC-R^2 close to 1) when there is a non-linear relationship.